# Hot to prevent duplicate entries in each row and two possible values can be entered into each cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to prevent duplicate entries in each row ,But in the same time two possible values can be entered into each cell "Yes" or "No".I used this formula in data validation =COUNTIF($B3:$J3,B3)=1  and applied to subsequent rows. The issue now , I need these range of cells accept "Yes" or "No" only by using any means even vba.

this link for the sample sheet:
https://easyupload.io/f4sjf3

[image]

Comment: So you have `10` columns, which cannot have duplicates, where ***two*** possible values can be entered into each cell?

Comment: yes, But the validation per each Row and not columns

Comment: If the validation is per row, by your requirement you can only enter `Yes` once and `No` once in the entire row - is that correct?

Comment: yes , only enter Yes once and No once in the entire row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow only "Yes" and "No", you can set up a simple validation rule (as List).
[image: Data Validation rule]. Depending on the settings of your computer, you will have to change the ";" in `"Yes";"No"` into a comma.

To ensure that only one "Yes" is entered per row, you could use the Worksheet_Change Trigger: Put the following code into the Worksheet Module of the according sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    dim checkRange As Range
    Set CheckRange = Range("A:J")

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Target
        If Not InterSect(cell, CheckRange ) Is Nothing And UCase(cell.Value) = "YES" Then
            Dim checkRow as Range, yesCount As Long
            Set checkRow = InterSect(cell.EntireRow, checkRange)
            yesCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(checkRow, "=YES")
            If yesCount > 1 Then
                MsgBox "Only on YES allowed per Range"
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Application.Undo
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Update**
To check only cells from A:J, you need to change 2 things. First the trigger should not fire if you modify a cell that is not within Columns A:J, and second you want to check only the number of "Yes" within that columns. I updated the code.

Comment: kindly, How to change (countif.entirerow) to only cells per each row from Column B to Column J ?